# Python IOError: Not a gzipped file (Gzip and Blowfish Encrypt/Compress)

Tags: python, encryption, gzip, blowfish, smb

I'm having some problems with python's built-in library `gzip`. Looked through almost every other stack question about it, and none of them seem to work.

MY PROBLEM IS THAT WHEN I TRY TO DECOMPRESS I GET THE `IOError`

I'm Getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mymodule.py", line 61, in
  return gz.read()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 245,
  readself._read(readsize)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 287, in
  _readself._read_gzip_header()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 181, in
  _read_gzip_header
raise IOError, 'Not a gzipped file'IOError: Not a gzipped file
```

This is my code to send it over the network, it might not make sense why i do things, but it's normally in a while loop and memory efficient, I just simplified it.

```
buffer = cStringIO.StringIO(output) #output is from a subprocess call
small_buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
small_string = buffer.read() #need a string to write to buffer 
gzip_obj = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=small_buffer,compresslevel=6, mode='wb')
gzip_obj.write(small_string)
compressed_str = small_buffer.getvalue()

blowfish = Blowfish.new('abcd', Blowfish.MODE_ECB)
remainder = '|'*(8 - (len(compressed_str) % 8))
compressed_str += remainder
encrypted = blowfish.encrypt(compressed_str)
#i send it over smb, then retrieve it later
```

Then this is the code that retrieves it:

```
#buffer is a cStringIO object filled with data from  retrieval
decrypter = Blowfish.new('abcd', Blowfish.MODE_ECB)
value = buffer.getvalue()
decrypted = decrypter.decrypt(value)
buff = cStringIO.StringIO(decrypted)
buff.seek(0)
gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buff)
return gz.read()
```

### Here's the problem

`return gz.read()`

Comment: Note that you should probably never use the ECB mode.

Comment: Why is that? This is my first time using encryption and compression

Comment: ECB is not a secure way to use a cipher, it never has been.  Look at the picture of the penguin.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29

Comment: Thanks for the tip... now for the other problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit:*** I think... you forgot to remove the padding before unzipping it. The code below works for me and gives me the same error if I don't remove the padding.

***Edit 2:*** Padding specification: The way you are doing padding I think requires you to pass the size of the padding since I assume the encryption algorithm could use the pipe character also. According to [RFC 3852, Section 6.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852#section-6.3), you should pad with the binary representation (not ASCII numbers) of the number of padding bytes needed. I have updated the code below to do my interpretation of the specification.

```
import gzip
import cStringIO
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish

#gzip and encrypt
small_buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
small_string = "test data"
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=small_buffer,compresslevel=6, mode='wb') as gzip_obj:
    gzip_obj.write(small_string)
compressed_str = small_buffer.getvalue()
blowfish = Blowfish.new('better than bad')
#remainder = '|'*(8 - (len(compressed_str) % 8))
pad_bytes = 8 - (len(compressed_str) % 8)
padding = chr(pad_bytes)*pad_bytes
compressed_str += padding
encrypted = blowfish.encrypt(compressed_str)
print("encrypted: {}".format(encrypted))



#decrypt and ungzip (pretending to be in a separate space here)
value = encrypted
blowfish = Blowfish.new('better than bad')
decrypted = blowfish.decrypt(value)
buff = cStringIO.StringIO(decrypted)
buff.seek(-1,2) #move to the last byte
pad_bytes = ord(buff.read(1)) #get the size of the padding from the last byte
buff.truncate(len(buff.getvalue()) - pad_bytes) #probably a better way to do this.
buff.seek(0)
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buff) as gz:
    back_home = gz.read()
print("back home: {}".format(back_home))
```

Comment: I'll test it then give you ALLLL the rep

Comment: Thank you so much @kobejohn! Glad you did the hard research for me!

Comment: @notbad.jpeg Glad it worked. everything went better than expected.